# How to compose stream operations in C++?

Tags: c++, stream, c++14

For a certain program, I have two functions that take an input and an output stream, doing some operation on the input and writing to the output. I can call them like this:

```
a(cin, cout);
b(cin, cout);
```

Say I want to run them in sequence, so that both the operations from a and b are applied. Currently, I'm using a `stringstream` as an intermediate iostream to store the result, like so:

```
stringstream buffer;
a(cin, buffer);
b(buffer, cout);
```

However, this pretty much negates the use of streams as all the data remains in memory for the intermediate step, even though both operations can be applied to streams with constant memory.

Is there a (standard) technique I can use to combine these operations, preferably without changing `a` and `b` too much? Also, if possible, I'd like to avoid boost.

Note: the functions here are just for example purposes. In the actual program both are methods on two objects.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to do something similar to std::endl (which is actually a function)?

Comment: *However, this pretty much negates the use of streams as all the data remains in memory for the intermediate step, even though both operations can be applied to streams with constant memory.* It's not clear from your post why this is a problem. I would think keeping the data in memory will be a plus from a performance standpoint.

Comment: @UKMonkey I'm not sure how that would work, but if it helps me create functionality equivalent to my second code sample, yes.

Comment: @RSahu: If I can compose the actions, I can send my data off directly, so if my input is, say, 1TB in size, I don't actually need 1TB of memory to store the intermediate result. So this actually is a problem.

Comment: @BertPeters, in that case, don't use a `stringstream` -- use `ofstream` and `ifstream`. That shouldn't change how `a` and `b` are implemented.

Comment: One major problem is that your first operation is designed to run to completion before the second operation is invoked. Even if you connect the streams together with a fifo or something, you're still not going to be doing both operations in parallel unless you also use another thread or restructure your operations to work on smaller chunks of data.

Comment: @DarkFalcon I was thinking some solution with an intermediate iostream which has its read and write methods overloaded or something, similar to Java's Stream api (specifically the map operation) works. Not sure if something like that exists.

Comment: But it still will not run in parallel unless you rewrite your two algorithms to work in chunks smaller than the whole stream or use 2 threads.

Comment: Running them in parallel is not exactly the goal here, just that my entire program can work on a stream of data, as both individual functions can. With the stringstream in between, I am forced to read everything into memory before writing it all out. The program itself may very well be single threaded.

Comment: Then you cannot until you, as I said, rewrite your two functions to work on single chunks of data rather than an entire stream.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a (standard) technique I can use to combine these operations, preferably without changing a and b too much? Also, if possible, I'd like to avoid boost.

What you really want is some sort of producer/consumer idiom where the producer reads from IN and the consumer writes to OUT. As far as I am aware, nothing in native C++ will help, although Boost has support for coroutines which is (to my knowledge) basically what you'll end up with.

Here's a way to implement your program that may allow you to make minimal changes to `a` and `b`. In this case, I assume you're reading a line-deliminated text file. If you're reading binary files, you'll want to read a fixed number of bytes, not a line.)

```
std::stringstream buffer;
std::string line;
while (std::getline(std::cin, line))
{
  std::istringstream iss(line);
  a(iss, buffer);
  b(buffer, std::cout);
}
```